# La autenticación LDAP falla con NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net

estoy realizando la autentificación con directorio activo en aspnet zero (realice los pasos que se presentan en la documentación) habilite el LDAP configure el dominio, usuario y contraseña. hasta alli todo bien pero cuando intento realizar el inicio de session me sale este excepción dentro de log, eh leido que sale porque el usuario no tiene asignado un email pero  no entiendo bien esa parte  que tiene que ver.

```
ERROR 2022-09-06 11:28:46,989 [7    ] Mvc.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Abp.Authorization.Users.AbpUser`1.SetNormalizedNames()
   at Abp.Authorization.AbpLogInManager`3.TryLoginFromExternalAuthenticationSourcesAsync(String userNameOrEmailAddress, String plainPassword, TTenant tenant)
   at Abp.Authorization.AbpLogInManager`3.LoginAsyncInternal(String userNameOrEmailAddress, String plainPassword, String tenancyName, Boolean shouldLockout)
   at Abp.Authorization.AbpLogInManager`3.<>c__DisplayClass36_0.<<LoginAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkManagerExtensions.WithUnitOfWorkAsync[TResult](IUnitOfWorkManager manager, Func`1 action, UnitOfWorkOptions options)
   at Abp.Authorization.AbpLogInManager`3.LoginAsync(String userNameOrEmailAddress, String plainPassword, String tenancyName, Boolean shouldLockout)
   at Sampler.ReceptorDeMuestras.Web.Controllers.TokenAuthController.GetLoginResultAsync(String usernameOrEmailAddress, String password, String tenancyName) in E:\Codigo2022\SamplerV6Summary\aspnet-core\src\Sampler.ReceptorDeMuestras.Web.Core\Controllers\TokenAuthController.cs:line 753
   at Sampler.ReceptorDeMuestras.Web.Controllers.TokenAuthController.Authenticate(AuthenticateModel model) in E:\Codigo2022\SamplerV6Summary\aspnet-core\src\Sampler.ReceptorDeMuestras.Web.Core\Controllers\TokenAuthController.cs:line 138
   at lambda_method1665(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Recomendaciones a considerar: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.